Why does the streitz and eam/alloy potential setting fail?
I used the following input file with streitz and eam/alloy potential settings for the simulation with LAMMPS.
variable         kb equal 8.617333262e-5
variable         t equal 300.0
variable         th equal 400.0
variable         tc equal 200.0

units            metal
dimension        3
newton           on
boundary         p p p
atom_style       atomic
neighbor         2.0 bin
timestep         0.0005

read_data        atomic_structure_atomic

#pair_style       hybrid vashishta lj/cut 12.0 airebo 3.0
#pair_coeff       * * vashishta ./Al2O3.vashishta O Al NULL NULL
pair_style       hybrid/overlay coul/streitz 12.0 wolf 0.3 eam/alloy airebo 3.0 lj/cut 12.0
pair_coeff       * * coul/streitz ./AlO.streitz O Al NULL NULL
pair_coeff       * * eam/alloy ./AlO.eam.alloy O Al NULL NULL
pair_coeff       * * airebo ./CH.airebo NULL NULL C C
pair_coeff       1 3 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       1 4 lj/cut 0.006199133907248657 3.692748434432002
pair_coeff       2 3 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
pair_coeff       2 4 lj/cut 0.042256836241015484 3.1764162195782846
#fix              11 all qeq/slater 1 12.0 1.0e-6 100 coul/streitz

compute          ke1 all ke/atom
variable         tem atom c_ke1/1.5/${kb}

#thermo           100
thermo           1000
thermo_style     custom step temp pxx pyy pzz press vol
velocity         all create $t 898758 mom yes rot yes dist gaussian
fix              11 all qeq/slater 1 12.0 1.0e-6 100 coul/streitz

min_style        cg
minimize         1.0e-8 1.0e-8 1000000 1000000

#1st euqilibrium in NPT ensamble
#thermo           100
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom step temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix              1 all npt temp $t $t 0.05 aniso 0.0 0.0 0.5
#dump             xyz_npt all xyz 10 dump_npt.xyz
dump             xyz_npt all xyz 1000 dump_npt.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_npt element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
#run              1000000
unfix            1
undump           xyz_npt
reset_timestep   0
write_data       atomic_structure_atomic_npt.dat

#2nd equilibrium in NVT ensamble
#thermo           100
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom temp pe ke etotal vol pxx pyy pzz press
fix              2 all nvt temp $t $t 0.05
#dump             xyz_nvt all xyz 10 dump_nvt.xyz
dump             xyz_nvt all xyz 1000 dump_nvt.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_nvt element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
#run              1000000
unfix            2
undump           xyz_nvt
reset_timestep   0

#Dividing the zone
variable         zbl equal zlo
variable         zbh equal zhi
variable         nla equal 100
variable         sca equal 1/${nla}
variable         len equal ${zbh}-${zbl}
variable         dz equal ${len}/${nla}
variable         zll equal ${zbl}+${dz}*2
variable         zlh equal ${zbl}+${dz}*6
variable         zrl equal ${zbh}-${dz}*6
variable         zrh equal ${zbh}-${dz}*2

region           reg_whole block INF INF INF INF ${zbl} ${zbh} units box
region           lef_fixed block INF INF INF INF INF ${zll} units box
region           hot block INF INF INF INF ${zll} ${zlh} units box
region           cold block INF INF INF INF ${zrl} ${zrh} units box
region           rig_fixed block INF INF INF INF ${zrh} INF units box
region           fixed_both union 2 lef_fixed rig_fixed

group            fixed region fixed_both
group            hot region hot
group            cold region cold
group            move subtract all fixed

reset_timestep   0
change_box       all boundary p p f

velocity         fixed set 0 0 0
fix              fixed fixed setforce 0 0 0

fix              3 hot langevin ${th} ${th} 0.05 14565 tally yes
fix              4 cold langevin ${tc} ${tc} 0.05 16576 tally yes
fix              5 all nve

variable         time equal step
variable         el equal f_3
variable         er equal f_4

compute          6 all chunk/atom bin/1d z lower ${sca} units reduced
#fix              7 all ave/chunk 1 10 10 6 v_tem file profile.heat
fix              7 all ave/chunk 1 10000 10000 6 v_tem file profile.heat
#thermo           100
thermo           2000
thermo_style     custom step temp ke pe etotal press vol
#dump             xyz_nve all xyz 10 dump_nve.xyz
dump             xyz_nve all xyz 1000 dump_nve.xyz
dump_modify      xyz_nve element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
#run              1000000
unfix            7
undump           xyz_nve
reset_timestep   0

fix              8 all ave/chunk 1 10000 10000 6 v_tem file time_average_temperature.dat
fix              eou all print 2000 "${time} ${el} ${er}" file energy.dat title "time e1 e2" screen no

#thermo           200
thermo           20000
thermo_style     custom step temp ke pe etotal press vol
#dump             fin all xyz 100 fin.xyz
dump             fin all xyz 20000 fin.xyz
dump_modify      fin element O Al C1 C2
run              500000
#run              2000000

After I launched the simulation, the calculation failed. The log.lammps file was empty and the output file from slurm system shows the following error message.
LAMMPS (17 Apr 2024)
[b08r4n08:32415:0:32415] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n10:24083:0:24083] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n09:26220:0:26220] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32412:0:32412] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32432:0:32432] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32416:0:32416] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32413:0:32413] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32436:0:32436] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32435:0:32435] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32427:0:32427] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32423:0:32423] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32429:0:32429] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32437:0:32437] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32431:0:32431] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32424:0:32424] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32414:0:32414] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32426:0:32426] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n08:32438:0:32438] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n10:24100:0:24100] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
Reading data file ...
  orthogonal box = (0 0 0) to (24.7284 23.795 1199.1959)
  1 by 1 by 96 MPI processor grid
  reading atoms ...
  83280 atoms
  read_data CPU = 0.465 seconds
Reading coul/streitz potential file ./AlO.streitz with DATE: 2015-02-19
Reading eam/alloy potential file ./AlO.eam.alloy with DATE: 2015-02-19
Reading airebo potential file ./CH.airebo with DATE: 2011-10-25
[b08r4n10:24084:0:24084] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n09:26224:0:26224] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
[b08r4n10:24104:0:24104] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
......
......
......
[b08r4n08:32422] [ 5] /public/home/zzs000227/lammps/lammps-17Apr2024/src/lmp_mpi[0x419e66]
[b08r4n08:32422] [ 6] /public/home/zzs000227/lammps/lammps-17Apr2024/src/lmp_mpi[0x41a7bc]
[b08r4n08:32422] [ 7] /public/home/zzs000227/lammps/lammps-17Apr2024/src/lmp_mpi[0x40ab08]
[b08r4n08:32422] [ 8] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x2b958c3183d5]
[b08r4n08:32422] [ 9] /public/home/zzs000227/lammps/lammps-17Apr2024/src/lmp_mpi[0x40cac5]
[b08r4n08:32422] *** End of error message ***
slurmstepd: error:  mpi/pmix_v3: _errhandler: b08r4n10 [2]: pmixp_client_v2.c:211: Error handler invoked: status = -25, source = [slurm.pmix.16950728.0:83]
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 16950728.0 ON b08r4n08 CANCELLED AT 2024-05-02T00:11:43 ***
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error:  mpi/pmix_v3: _errhandler: b08r4n09 [1]: pmixp_client_v2.c:211: Error handler invoked: status = -25, source = [slurm.pmix.16950728.0:62]
slurmstepd: error:  mpi/pmix_v3: _errhandler: b08r4n08 [0]: pmixp_client_v2.c:211: Error handler invoked: status = -25, source = [slurm.pmix.16950728.0:21]
srun: error: b08r4n10: tasks 64-95: Segmentation fault
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=16950728.0
srun: error: b08r4n08: tasks 0-31: Segmentation fault
srun: error: b08r4n09: tasks 32-63: Segmentation fault

Would anyone please tell me why the calculation fails with suggestions/comments?
Thank you in advance.

Dear All, In my simulation system, I need to use the hybrid style potential to describe the interaction Al, O and C elements. In such case, I cannot use 'coul/streitz' flag in the 'fix qeq/slater' command. I have to write out the parameter file that contains the interactions for all atom types but I do not know how write out the parameters and how to obtain these parameters. Would anyone please give me some suggestions/hints on this parameter file? Thank you in advance.
